# Getting empty response from gRPC call

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc, grpc-node

I have a simple gRPC server and client. The server and client are working fine (I assume since I am getting a response and no error). However the response is empty which I have no idea why.

Here is the proto `message.proto`

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

message Msg {
    int32 timeStamp = 1;
    string text = 2;
    string sender = 3;
}

message Empty {}

service MsgService{
    rpc AllMessages (Empty) returns (MsgList) {}
}

message MsgList {
    repeated Msg msgs = 1;
}
```

and `server.js`

```js
const grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');
const PROTO_PATH = "./message.proto";
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');

const options = {
    keepCase: true,
    longs: String,
    enums: String,
    defaults: true,
    oneofs: true
}

const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH, options);
const msgProto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);

const server = new grpc.Server();
let savedMessages = [
    { timeStamp: 1, text: "lorem", sender: "alex" },
    { timeStamp: 2, text: "ipsum", sender: "bob" },
    { timeStamp: 3, text: "dolor", sender: "alex" },
    { timeStamp: 4, text: "net", sender: "bob" }
];

server.addService(msgProto.MsgService.service, {
    AllMessages: (_, callback) => {
        callback(null, savedMessages);
    }
})

server.bindAsync("127.0.0.1:50051", grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(), (err, port) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(port);
    server.start();
    console.log("Server running at 127.0.0.1:50051");
})
```

and `client.js`

```js
const grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
const PROTO_PATH = "./message.proto";

const options = {
    keepCase: true,
    longs: String,
    enums: String,
    defaults: true,
    oneofs: true,
};

var packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH, options);

const MsgService = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).MsgService;

const client = new MsgService(
    "localhost:50051",
    grpc.credentials.createInsecure()
);

client.AllMessages({}, (err, msg) => {
    // console.log(err);
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(msg);
    // console.log(msg);
})
```

and the repsonse I am getting

```js
{ msgs: [] }
```

If it helps , I was following this blog post https://daily.dev/blog/build-a-grpc-service-in-nodejs

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MsgList` message definition is a message with a single field called `msgs` that has the type `repeated Msg`. The object that you send should have that form. So, it should be an object with a single field called `msgs` that has an array of objects that match the format of the `Msg` message definition. Your `savedMessages` variable is not that, it's just an array, which is why sending it doesn't get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks.
It works fine now.
Probably that blog has some errors or something's changed.

Comment: Yes, that is an error in that blog post.